# Problema de validación al editar datos precargados en función de una selección de opción anterior en un formulario

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Tengo un formulario que contiene dos elementos de selección: uno para seleccionar una fuerza y ​​otro para seleccionar un rango. Las opciones del elemento de selección de rango dependen de la fuerza seleccionada, por lo que estoy usando una solicitud AJAX para cargar las opciones relacionadas según la ID de la fuerza seleccionada.

El formulario funciona correctamente al crear un nuevo registro. Sin embargo, al editar un registro precargado, el valor de ID forzado ya está establecido, por lo que el detector de eventos de cambio para el elemento de selección forzada no se activa y las opciones de clasificación relacionadas no se actualizan en consecuencia. Como resultado, la validación falla ya que el usuario puede seleccionar una opción de rango no válida que pertenece a otra fuerza.

```
$('#selectedForce').change(function () {
    var selectedForceId = $(this).val();
    loadRanks(selectedForceId);
});

function loadRanks(selectedForceId) {
    $('#selectedRank').empty().append('<option selected hidden value="">Select</option>');
    if (selectedForceId) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/FamilyContact/GetRanksByForce',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { forceId: selectedForceId },
            success: function (ranks) {
                $.each(ranks, function (index, rank) {
                    $('#selectedRank').append($('<option>', {
                        value: rank.Id,
                        text: rank.Description
                    }));
                });
            },
            error: function () {},
            complete: function () {
                $('#selectedRank').selectpicker('refresh');
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#selectedRank').selectpicker('refresh');
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#selectedForce').change(function () {
        var selectedForceId = $(this).val();
        if (selectedForceId == 1 || selectedForceId == 2 || selectedForceId == 3) {
            $('.military').show();
        } else {
            $('.military').hide();
        }
        loadRanks(selectedForceId);
    });
});
```

El siguente codigo es el controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditFamilyMember(FamilyMember familyMember, string prefix, string suffix)
{
    string errorMessage = "";
    if (FamilyMember.ValidateFamilyMember(familyMember, ref errorMessage))
    {
        var declaration = _context.Declaration.AsNoTracking()
            .Where(d => d.ID == familyMember.DeclarationID)
            .Include(d => d.FamilyMembers)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (!declaration.ValidateFamilyMember(familyMember, ref errorMessage, true))
        {
            return RedirectToAction("EditFamilyMember", new { familyMember.DeclarationID, errorMessage });
        }

        if (familyMember.RankID != null)
        {
            string rankDescription = _api.GetRankById((int)familyMember.RankID)?.Description;
            familyMember.RankDescription = rankDescription;
        }

        if (familyMember.BranchID != null)
        {
            string branchDescription = _api.GetBranchById((int)familyMember.BranchID)?.Description;
            familyMember.BranchDescription = branchDescription;
        }

        if (familyMember.EmployerProvinceID == null)
        {
            familyMember.EmployerCityID = null;
        }

        if (familyMember.IsAlive == true)
        {
            familyMember.DeathProvinceID = null;
            familyMember.DeathCityID = null;
        }

        if (familyMember.IsLivingWithMember == true)
        {
            familyMember.Address.ProvinceId = null;
            familyMember.Address.CityId = null;
        }

        var completeCuil = prefix + familyMember.Cuil + suffix;
        familyMember.Cuil = completeCuil;

        _context.Update(familyMember);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("FamilyContact", new { id = familyMember.DeclarationID });
    }

    return RedirectToAction("EditFamilyMember", new { familyMember.DeclarationID, errorMessage });
}
```

Comment: Saludos. Tienes dos veces `$('#selectedForce').change(....);`; deja solo uno; a mi parecer el que debes dejar es el que esta dentro de `$(document).ready(...)`.